# Spin distribution in a single slit electron diffraction pattern?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin

If I send a beam of electrons through a slit to form a diffraction pattern, would there be any repeatable distribution of spin states along this pattern? In other words, do we know what spin vs. position (along the pattern) would look like, if the spin of each particle was measured when it hit the "viewing screen"?

I'm under the impression that - in theory - the answer would be no, since the spin & momentum operators [commute](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/do-spin-and-momentum-commute.396031/). I couldn't find any references to related experiments in a journal search.

Edit: I asked about a repeatable distribution, but "predictable to any degree" might be a better word choice.